# In Snowflake , any one used Merging into table when matched then insert into select statement

Tags: merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, insert-select

In the snowflake ,Merge into when Matched then insert () values () , this is working fine but i have a case where the insert should be from select statements

Merge into when Matched then insert () select * from dummy;  - but this is failing with Errors

Comment: with which error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the MERGE command allows only:

`INSERT [(<col_name> [, ...])] VALUES (<expr> [, ...])`

It does not handle the **SELECT** statement inside an **INSERT** statement, but it is possible to use a subquery in the **USING** clause and there you should possibly pass your **SELECT** and transformations, it could also be a CTE (Common Table Expressions). For example:

```
merge into target using (
   SELECT k, max (v) as v FROM src group by k) as b --<-- Your subquery
on target.k = b.k
when not matched then insert (k, v) values (b.k, b.v);
```

or with CTE expression:

```
with b as (
    SELECT k, max (v) as v FROM src group by k --<-- Your subquery
) 
merge into target using b
on target.k = b.k
when not matched then insert (k, v) values (b.k, b.v);
```

Reference: [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html), [CTE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html#working-with-ctes-common-table-expressions)